# Добавление картинки в новость PHP

Tags: php

есть форма в которой два инпута с заголовком и текстом новости, и также кнопка submit. С добавлением новости проблем не возникало до тех пор, пока не захотелось добавить картинки к этой новости. Первое, что пришло на ум, это в базе данных к таблице новостей добавить ещё одное поле с названием картинки, которое нужно добавить и при выводе новости просто добавить тег `<img src='image/полеСназваниемКартинки'>`. Но загрузить картинку и отправить данные в базу одной кнопкой не получится, а если отдельно сначала картинку загружать,а  потом новость, то как потом привязывать картинку к новости? Я не силён в php, новичок. Шарясь в форумах в поисках ответов очень часто натыкаюсь, что русское комьюнити очень негативное и начинают оскорблять, мол иди гугли и документацию почитай. Я лично с таким не сталкивался, но понемногу начинаю разочаровываться в русском комьюнити

Comment: @Jean-Claude я и не предлагал грузить картинку, а лишь название картинки.

Comment: @Jean-Claude если не надо в форумах шариться, то и сам сайт, на котором вы сейчас находитесь, теряет свой смысл

Comment: @Jean-Claude, что-то ваши комментарии вообще никак не коррелируют ни с вопросом, ни с комментариями автора...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пишете, что

> Но загрузить картинку и отправить данные в базу одной кнопкой не получится

на самом деле это не так.

Можно сделать сабмит формы и изображения в одной форме по одной кнопке.

В теге `<form>` нужно добавить `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.
Добавить на форму тег `<input name="yourFile" type="file" />`.

Затем в скрипте, который обрабатывает форму получить картинку из переменной `$_FILES['yourFile']`.
Сохранить картинку на диске.
Путь к файлу сохранить в базе.

Чтобы это реализовать не нужно форумы или книги, всё описано хорошо на русском в оф.документации [php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/)

Comment: боже, я при нажатии кнопки отправлял толлько новость и пытался вытащить название картинки, которую я не загружал из-за чего и выскакивала ошибка. Спасибо)